# Why is tsc command not found in child package in yarn workspace?

Tags: yarn-v2

I'm using yarn version 3.2.4. I have a package.json in my root that looks like this:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc --build",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  }
}
```

In packages/foo, I have this package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc --build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  }
}
```

When I run `yarn compile` from the root, tsc compiles correctly. But this fails:

```
cd packages/foo
yarn compile
```

`command not found: tsc`

If I change the child packages to include typescript as a devDependency then it works.

Why aren't the devDependencies inherited from the parent package.json?

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this? I just encountered this on trying to update to yarn v3.